# Get data from Websockets Dart and pull it in the UI

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to get  data from my websockets, also I am using Signal R package, so now I am trying to get data from json like this:

```
 Future<String?> fetchGps() async {
    final hubConnection =
        HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl('http://secure/secure').build();
    await hubConnection.start();
    if (hubConnection.state == HubConnectionState.Connected) {
      await hubConnection
          .invoke('GetGPSDateTime')
          .then((value) => print(value));
    }
    hubConnection.onclose(({error}) {
      throw Exception(error);
    });
    return null;
  }

  late Future<String?> futureGPS;

  @override
  void initState() {
    futureGPS = fetchGps();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: FutureBuilder<String?>(
          future: futureGPS,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String?> snapshot) {
            return Text(snapshot.data ?? '');
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

I don't understand how can I get  data from websockets and push it to uu and I am getting the blank sreen from the ui thread. So if there is any cance to get data from websockets which is not json, but just an object and pull it to the ui?

Comment: Can you please share your class  GpsClass.

Comment: @HardikMehta I updated my question and add nedeed class

Comment: is it print with jsonDecode ? or just value.ToString() ?

Comment: @HardikMehta it prints just value.ToString()

Comment: Can you share log with jsonDecode and Share here

Comment: You can write jsonEncode instead of jsonDecode and check

Answer (score 0):

From your code it seems the `hubConnection.invoke('GetGPSDateTime')` is actual `Future` object. Your component needs to be rewritten as:

```dart
late final HubConnection hubConnection; // Assuming the type is HubConnection
Future<String?>? futureGPS;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl('http://secure/secure')
    .build();

  Future.microtask(() async {
    await hubConnection.start();

    // Here is where we assign the actual Future object
    futureGPS = hubConnection.invoke('GetGPSDateTime')
  });
}

@override
void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
  
  // Make sure to dispose of the hubConnection
  // hubConnection.close(); or
  // hubConnection.cancel();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: futureGPS != null ? 
      FutureBuilder<String?>(
        future: futureGPS,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String?> snapshot) {
          return Text(snapshot.data ?? '');
        },
      )
      : null,
  );
)
```

Comment: I found the solution. I researched that in my case websocket return the list of objects or just object, so to take the needed element from response, I need to use syntaxis like this: [0]['name'] and it return the name from the API. Also for constant refreshing I decided to use streams with static future